# Meaning of ご縁 and 縁 in this context

Tags: translation, meaning, manga

I came across this interview, where the speaker mentioned both ご縁 and 縁
and this is from this particular clip -> https://clyp.it/v1uobgr2

I managed to transcribe it (I believe?), but I'm not sure how would I go about translating the first part, especially to distinguish between ご縁 and 縁.

What I heard was

> それから、Staffさんとの沢山の**ご縁**があって
>   作品の中でも沢山の**縁**があって
>   素晴らしい方々と色んな**縁**でこうして出来たのが
>   舞台Haikyuu!!だと思ってます。

I know that 縁 has such a deep meaning in Japanese, so I was wondering if there is any way to make it easier to understand?

PS. Yes this is an interview related to the manga called Haikyuu!!

**Edit: The audio link has been fixed.**

---

Also I struggled to transcribe this particular bit from the same interview.

-> https://clyp.it/ibxy43to

I could only hear

> 本当にxxxx良かったです。ありがとうございます。

so I was wondering, if anyone can help me shed some light on this.

Thank you!

Comment: What reading are they using for 縁 here?

Comment: @Maru The audio clip is cut off at 縁があって so I cannot hear the latter half of the sentence.

Comment: @Chocolate My apologies I have uploaded the wrong audio cut. I have fixed the link now.

Comment: In the 2nd audio clip he says 「本当に**出会えて**良かったです。ありがとうございます。」

Comment: @istrasci 三回とも「えん」って言ってます　（そういえば「[縁]{ゆかり}」と「[縁]{えん}」ってちょっと意味が違いますね）

Answer (score 3):

Some spiritually-inclined person might think of 「人とご縁があって」 as "the universe brought us together", a religious person might say "God brought us together", etc.

However, I think that ご縁 is quite similar to the sentiment in "**it was meant to be**".

In the context you give, this is difficult to make sound natural, so I would tend to something like

> スタッフさんとの沢山のご縁があって、作品の中でも沢山の縁があって、素晴らしい方々と色んな縁でこうして出来たのが舞台Haikyuu!!だと思ってます。
>
> I feel very lucky to meet the staff, the production likewise went very smoothly / just flowed naturally, and the encounters with all these wonderful people is how *Haikyū!!* came to be.

I think the difference between 縁 and ご縁 is just the usual difference between 〇 and ご〇・お〇 (the one with ご・お is more polite).

Answer (score 3):

The way 縁 is used in your clip seems to be rather vague and strikes me as [phatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phatic_expression). If I heard someone use 縁 like this, I'd either think they are the sort of person who very earnestly believes in 縁 or are trying hard to find a simple, agreeable word that will please everyone.

I interpret these uses of 縁 in the following ways:

> Staffさんとの沢山のご縁があって
>   → *had many nice-meetings with the staff* = "was happy working with them"
>
> 作品の中でも沢山の縁があって
>   → *had many nice-meetings in the work* = "knew many people / learned a lot from such a great work"
>
> 素晴らしい方々と色んな縁で
>   → *with all sorts of nice-meetings and wonderful people* = "by a fortunate collaboration of wonderful people"

Basically 縁 is a concept widespread among East Asians, typified by [the legend of red string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_string_of_fate), that every association between people is divine match-making, and you should treasure and be grateful for having good relationship with someone. Based on this, people often use 縁 casually when they feel "happy, lucky to be or doing something together", to indirectly praise people around them.

Answer (score 1):

縁 is one of the difficult concepts to translate into English because I cannot find a comparable concept in English. I explain 縁 to my American friends as life circumstances which has brought people together.

In this sentence, I do not know who is talking, so I cannot specify some parts, but I might translate:

> And, I think that we are able to produce this stage play, Haikyuu!!
>   because of the wonderful connections with wonderful staff and
>   co-workers.